# make code async with forJoinPool

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, runnable

Hello I have with try catch structure and want to make code async in finally statement. I try to put this part into lambda and cast to task, to put it ForkJoinPool, but there is the Class Cast Exception. How to make async this part of code better. Does I have to use atomic or volatile before fields?

```
    public class Record {
        private String actionDetails;

        public void setActionDetails(String actionDetails) {
            this.actionDetails = actionDetails;
        }
    }

    public class Recorder {
        private Record record;

        public void record(Record record){
            this.record = record;
        }
    }

public class Test {
    private static Recorder recorder = new Recorder();
    private static StringBuilder builder;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // other code
            builder.append("Test");

        } finally {
            Runnable runnable = () -> {
                final Record record = new Record();
                record.setActionDetails(builder.toString());
                recorder.record(record);
            };

            ForkJoinTask<?> task = (ForkJoinTask<?>)runnable;

            ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
            pool.invoke(task);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't really see what you are trying to do but it raises several red flags for me.

Comment: Something like logging a failed attempt, is it what you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: Sorry for wrong code.

Answer (score 0):

I mean this way:

```
ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
pool.submit(() -> {
        final Record record = new Record();
        record.setActionDetails(builder.toString());
        recorder.record(record);
});
```

but Is it need to use some modifier before fields ?